Cannot run .py scripy with docker interpreter
Below are my docker settings on pycharm:
python interpreter
docker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 570, in <module>
    pydevconsole.start_client(host, port)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 482, in start_client
    client, server_transport = make_rpc_client(client_service, host, port)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_rpc.py", line 11, in make_rpc_client
    client_transport, server_transport = open_transports_as_client((host, port))
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_transport.py", line 231, in open_transports_as_client
    client_socket.connect(addr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Couldn't connect to console process.
Process finished with exit code 1

But if I go command line and use 'docker run -it coady/pylucene', I can successfully use the library 'lucene'
solve this problem and make the script runable on pycharm
